# Checking whether a user already exists in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-fapi, drupal-alter

When a user enters his login information and hits submit, i want to check if the user already exists or not.
So, i have the following two questions
1. Which hook is needed to be implemented , for the case when user hits the submit button on the login form. I need the username entered by the user.
2. How to check if a user already exists in drupal or not programmatically ?

Some sample code would be really appreciated.
Please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 22):

Drupal 7 provides a function to get a user object by name :

```
$user = user_load_by_name($name);
if(!$user){
    // User doesn't exist
} 
else {
    // User exists
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7

Comment: This is a heavy-handed solution as it loads the entire user object, just to validate the existence of a user by name. Also, if you're loading a user, do not use a variable named `$user` as it could easily be confused with the `global $user` which is the current user account.

Comment: you can also use `user_load_by_mail` in case you're searching by mail: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with `hook_form_alter`:

```
function module_(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $user_login_forms = array('user_login', 'user_login_block');
  if (in_array($form_id, $user_login_forms)) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_validate_function';
  }
}

function my_validate_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
  // Drupal 6:
  if (!db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = '%s';", $name))) {
    // User doesn't exist
  }
  // Drupal 7:
  if (!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = :name;", array(':name' => $name))->fetchField()) {
    // User doesn't exist
   }
}
```

It's better to query the DB directly in this case than than using `user_load` as it hooks into other modules as well.

Comment: I'd forgotten you could do that with `hook_form_alter`! Kudos! Deleting my answer.

Comment: This does not work for Drupal 7. This does: 
`$result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE uid = :uid", array(':uid' => $uid))->fetchField();
    if ($result == 0) {
        // User doesn't exist
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;`

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7, substitute for this in the validation function:

```
if (!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = :name", array(':name' => $name))->fetchField()) {
  // User doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is almost 2 years old, but user_authenticate does this nicely.

```
$existing_user = user_authenticate($name,$password);
if($existing_user)
  // user exists
else
  // user doesn't exist
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: this needs the password, this is a bad answer.

Comment: If the user is entering a username and password why would this be a bad solution? The password isn't getting displayed and I'm simply using the password that was given. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look on these 2 modules for inspiration: [friendly_register](https://www.drupal.org/project/friendly_register) and [username_check](https://www.drupal.org/project/username_check).